# c++ pass function to thread pool

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I am practising with threads and thread concurrency and I want to make my own thread pool. For this I have a vector of threads, those threads will wait on a condition variable to get the next function to execute from another vector.

But I have troubles storing/passing/executing functions with unknown arguments. Can someone please give me a hint how to do this or what i need for this?

**working EDIT:**

Adding task:

```
ThreadPool tp(10);
tp.execute(std::bind(print, i));

void print(int i) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

void ThreadPool::execute(const std::function<void()> function) {
    l.lock();
    if (running) {
        queue.push_back(function);
        cv.notify_one();
    } else {
        // TODO error
        std::cout << "err execute()\n";    
    }
    l.unlock();
}
```

Thread loop:

```
// set up threads in constructor
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   threads.push_back(std::thread(&ThreadPool::thread_loop, std::ref(*this), i));
}

static void ThreadPool::thread_loop(ThreadPool &pool, int id) {
    pool.o.lock();
    std::cout << "pool-" << pool.id << "-thread-" << id << " started\n";
    pool.o.unlock();
    std::function<void()> function;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(pool.m, std::defer_lock);

    while (pool.running || pool.queue.size() > 0) {
        ul.lock();
        while (pool.queue.size() == 0) {
            pool.cv.wait(ul);
        }
        pool.l.lock();
        if (pool.queue.size() == 0) {
            pool.l.unlock();
            continue;
        }
        function = pool.queue.at(0);
        pool.queue.erase(pool.queue.begin());
        pool.l.unlock();
        ul.unlock();
        function();
    }
}
```

Comment: This begs of `std::function<void()>`. With that, you can pass whatever 0-argument callable you want (function, function object, lambda, result of `std::bind`, you name it) into your threadpool and it will just work.

Comment: You can do m_threads.push_back(std::thread(&InitThreadsFoo, m_threads.size())); but I too would like to know how to reassign existing thread from vector to take over another function, or assign a function to an already existing thread that's already been used.

Comment: @Andrey Turkin thank you this works great!

Comment: @ReturnVoid see edit ^^

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the function + its arguments as variadic template:

```
template<class Task, class ...Args>
void ThreadPool::execute(Task&& task, Args&& ... args) {
    l.lock();
    if (running) {
        queue.emplace_back(std::bind(std::forward<Task>(task),std::forward<Args>(args)...));
        cv.notify_one();
    } else {
        // TODO error
        std::cout << "err execute()\n";    
    }
    l.unlock();
}
```

Example use:

```
ThreadPool tp(/*whatever you pass the thread pool constructor*/);
tp.execute(printf,"hello from the threadpool.");
```